# consume npm package with pip

Tags: python, npm, pip

we have multiple services in nodejs and python. sharing code between nodejs services is easy - we just publish a package to our artifactory instance. now, i want to use some data from that package, specifically json files, in a python service.

there is this way:

```
npm view package@version | grep tgz | xargs wget | tar xf
```

i omitted some arguments for brevity. 
this allows to get json files as part of service initialization script, but it goes against a lot of conventions in our infrastructure.

what i want is to be able to make pip consume non-py files from package. other packages do have json files installed, so i tried to copy that.
in my npm package, i have setup.py:

```py
import os
from setuptools import setup


setup(
    name='my_package',
    version='0.0.{}'.format(os.getenv('BUILD_NUMBER', '1')),
    py_modules=['my_package'],
    package_data={'my_package': ['package/dist/json/*.json']},
    include_package_data=True
)
```

and MANIFEST.in:

```
include package/dist/json/*.json
```

then in python service i have requirements.txt:

```
https://$USER:$PASSWORD@artifactory.hostname/some/path/my-package-0.0.12345.tgz
```

package installs successfully, but no json files are extracted.
what am i missing?